# Creating snapshot of aem instance

Tags: linux, aem

I have to take a backup of aem instance on linux machine. Could not find good documentation to know how to achieve this. Please share the related information and also how its different from copying quickstart to different location.

Comment: do you want the entire repository, or just some content?

Comment: There was a talk at the adaptTo conference a couple of years ago. Adobe Managed Services made snapshots too. They ended with making 5-10 disk snapshot, until they got something that would start again. https://adapt.to/2015/en/schedule/aws-implementation.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to accomplish. AEM offers an OOTB backup functionality: http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/backup/content/admin.html

If you need only some content, the Package Manager is a straightforward approach.

However, it seems you need to backup the whole instance. In this case, shutdown the instance safely, and then you can compress (tar/zip) the whole `crx-quickstart` directory and move/upload it to your backup location.

Additionally, depending on your AEM version, and after you have that first backup, you could also execute `oak-run` utility to compact the instance, which is also a recommended maintenance task.